# namespace questions and difference between IDE's

Tags: c++

Ive been following along with some c++ tutorials on youtube and I cant seem to get this code to work, I use code blocks and this person uses visual c++. Is there a difference between them somehow? before I did cin >> std::Asalary; she asked what whould happen if you ran this code, she got an error and I got zero which makes sense, so im kinda lost on both of these problems. any help whould be epic, thanks in advance.

```
 #include <iostream>

 using std::cout;
 using  std::endl;
 using std::string;


 namespace main1 {
 double Asalary;
 double MonthSal = Asalary/12;


 }

 int main()
 {
     cout << "enter your annual salary" << endl;
    cin >> main1::Asalary;
    cout << main1::MonthSal << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Most likely the issue is you have `using std::string;` in your code, but you never `#include <string>`, which is where `std::string` actually lives.  The standard allows header files to include other standard header files, but that can/does change between implementations.

Comment: What matters is what compiler you use (GCC for CodeBlocks vs MSVC for Visual Studio), not what IDE.

Comment: okay, makes a bit more sense, thanks guys

Comment: When defined, `ASalary` is initialised with a value of zero since it has static storage duration. That value is used to initialise `MonthSal` (using the definition and initialisation `double MonthSal = ASalary/12`).   The code will always output the value `0`, since `main1::MonthSal` is initialised to zero, and its value never changed by your code.  You seem to expect that the definition `double MonthSal = Asalary/12`  set up some magical means by which `main1::MonthSal` is automatically changed whenever `main1::ASalary` changes (e.g. is read from the user).  C++ simply does not work that way.

Answer (score 3):

You have at global scope:

```
namespace main1 
{
    double Asalary;
    double MonthSal = Asalary/12;
}
```

and then you do:

```
cin >> main1::Asalary;
cout << main1::MonthSal << endl;
```

So, you seem to expect `main1::MonthSal` to magically be annual salary divided by twelve, because you told the program once.

That's not how C++ works. `double MonthSal = Asalary/12;` is executed only once, before annual salary is entered.

Then, if you change annual salary, the monthly salary will not update.

I know that's not the question you are asking, but this is important and will hinder your understanding of C++ in a significant way.

Comment: got it thanks, just curious, what is your computer programming background